# Javascript Promise Exception Handling

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to understand promise exception handling in the following scenario. The second debugger statement stops first, and logs an error. Why is this? I thought the exception block could only be entered if the 'then' block threw an error?

```
api.then(response => {
  debugger; //1
  dispatch(fetchReceive(response)); //never executes
})
.catch((err) => {
  debugger; //2
  console.error(err); //err.status = 404
});
```

I'm using the following npm packages:

```
"babel-cli": "6.14.0",
"babel-core": "6.9.1",
"babel-loader": "6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.10.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.8.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.8.0",
"babel-polyfill": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
"babel-preset-es2017": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
"babel-register": "6.9.0",
```

Comment: it can also be entered, without going through `.then`, if `api` is a rejected promise - so your question really has nothing to do with babel, it's just about how Promises work

Comment: Actually it depends on 'api' because 'api' might throws a rejected promise or throws an exception while processing it. 'then' block always executed if api executes successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Error` in a `Promise` or in a `.then` will propagate down the `Promise` chain until it meets the first handler, which can be one of these two:

```
.then(function(){}, function(err){}) // second callback is the handler
.catch(function(err){})
```

where the `.catch` option is actually just syntactic sugar for:

```
.then(null, function(err){})
```

In your code the `.then` does not contain a handler and so the `Error` in `api` propagates to `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Promises are not actions, they're values. `api` is the result of some call, and that result might already be an error.

```
const api = Promise.reject(new Error("I'm rejected!"));

api
  .then(value => console.log("I'm resolved!", value))
  .catch(err => console.error("I'm rejected!", err.message));
```

In this case, `.then()` will be skipped and `.catch()` will be called.